# Fast way to find sequences between filepaths/filenames

Tags: python

I'm trying to find file sequences between filenames in a given list of filenames. However the position of the potential file sequence is unknown. It may be at any position in the filename.

There are the following rules for sequences:

1. Sequences are always of the same length. So 01 - 12 and 070 - 110 are valid sequences. 1 - 12 and 70 - 110 are not.
2. Sequences are allowed to have gaps. 01, 02, 05, 10, 21 would be a valid sequence.

Example:

Input:

```
[
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_xyz_05.png",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc09_xyz_05.png",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc10_xyz_05.JPG",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc15_xyz_05.JPG",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc16_xyz_05.png",
"fde305be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abcde_05.png",
"fde309be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abcde_05.png",
"fde310be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abcde_05.png"
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
[["fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_xyz_05.png",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc09_xyz_05.png",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc16_xyz_05.png"], (22, 24)],

[["fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc10_xyz_05.JPG",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc15_xyz_05.JPG"], (22, 24)],

[["fde305be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abcde_05.png",
"fde309be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abcde_05.png",
"fde310be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abcde_05.png"], (3, 6)]
]
```

Where (22, 24) and (3, 6) describe the position of the sequence in the string. For the last one I don't particularly care if it's (3, 6) or (4, 6). But either of the two. The list elements (input and output) don't have to be in order.

I have a working version, but it is really slow, gets drastically slower with the amount of filenames and sequences, and is about a 100 lines of code.

Is there a faster and simpler way to get the desired output?

Here is my current solution. I know there are parts, where I could optimize it, like ignoring sequences where I know that the filename I'm checking can't be part of that sequence anymore given the sequences are pre-sorted etc., but I feel like my approach is flawed from the beginning and that there are better ways to approach this problem.

```
import os
import re


def get_seq_position(this_path, other_path, compiled_pattern,
                     seq_position = None):
    """
    Finds out, if there is a sequence between two file paths and returns either
    the position of the sequence in a tuple or None if there is no sequence
    between the two paths.
    """

    if not seq_position is None:
        return get_seq_position_range(this_path, other_path, seq_position)

    this_name = os.path.basename(this_path)
    other_name = os.path.basename(other_path)
    this_dir = os.path.dirname(this_path)
    other_dir = os.path.dirname(other_path)

    if this_dir != other_dir:
        return None

    this_dir_len = 0
    other_dir_len = 0

    if this_dir:
        this_dir_len = len(this_dir) + 1
        other_dir_len = len(other_dir) + 1

    # Sequences are more often towards the end [::-1].
    matches_this = list(compiled_pattern.finditer(this_name))[::-1]
    matches_other = list(compiled_pattern.finditer(other_name))[::-1]
    matches_this_count = len(matches_this)
    matches_other_count = len(matches_other)

    if (matches_this_count == 0
        or matches_this_count != matches_other_count):
        return None

    for match_this, match_other in zip(matches_this, matches_other):
        this_test_name = "".join([this_name[:match_this.start(0)],
                                  this_name[match_this.end(0):]])
        other_test_name = "".join([other_name[:match_other.start(0)],
                                   other_name[match_other.end(0):]])

        match_this_value = match_this.group(0)
        match_other_value = match_other.group(0)

        if len(match_this_value) != len(match_other_value):
            return None

        if this_test_name == other_test_name:
            if int(match_this_value) != int(match_other_value):
                return (this_dir_len + match_this.start(0),
                        other_dir_len + match_this.end(0))

    return None


def get_seq_position_range(this_path, other_path, seq_position):
    """
    Does the same as get_seq_position() except that it takes the sequence
    position (tuple) if the position is already known for one of the two
    given paths. This is a lot faster than get_seq_position().
    """

    seq_start, seq_end = seq_position

    this_merged_path = "".join([this_path[:seq_start], this_path[seq_end:]])
    other_merged_path = "".join([other_path[:seq_start], other_path[seq_end:]])
    this_sequence = this_path[seq_start:seq_end]
    other_sequence = other_path[seq_start:seq_end]

    if (this_merged_path == other_merged_path 
        and len(this_sequence) == len(other_sequence)
        and int(this_sequence) != int(other_sequence)):
        return seq_position

    return None


def create_sequences(filepaths, flavor = ""):
    """
    Creates the list of sequences as follows. seq_position is a tuple
    containing the position of the sequence in the filepath.
    [[[filepath_1, filepath_2, ...], seq_position],
     [[filepath_a, filepath_b, ...], seq_position], ...]
    """

    filepaths.sort()
    compiled_pattern = re.compile("\d+")

    sequences = []
    for filepath in filepaths:
        for sequence in sequences:
            filepath_to_check = sequence[0][0]
            seq_position = get_seq_position(filepath_to_check, filepath,
                                            compiled_pattern, sequence[1])

            if seq_position is None:
                continue
            else:
                sequence[0].append(filepath)
                if sequence[1] is None:
                    sequence[1] = seq_position
                break
        else:
            sequences.append([[filepath], None])

    if flavor == "nuke" or flavor == "nuke_info":
        return sequences_to_nuke(sequences, flavor)

    return sequences


def main(dir_path):
    filepaths = [
                 os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
                 for filename
                 in os.listdir(dir_path)
                 if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, filename))
                ]

    seqs = create_sequences(filepaths)

    for seq in seqs:
        print(seq)

    return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(r"C:\path\to\sequence_folder")
```

Comment: you probably want to break your n2 complexity by using some kind of key and dict. why do you have 8,9,16, then 10,15. I fail to see the logic

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I first asked myself the same question until I realises that first sequence was for png files, while the second was for jpg...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre As Serge already pointed out, it's because of the jpg. I edited it to make it more clear. However without that there would be simpler solutions. Hence why it's in there. About the suggestion with dicts. I don't know how to do that. I have to check any other sequence anyway, don't I? How would dicts help here?

Comment: first you should create 1 group per extension, that would break the complexity.

Comment: Do all filenames have the same length? Putting files in same-length buckets could drastically cut down on the n2 factor.

Comment: @alexis No they don't. I didn't know that could make a difference. I edited the names in the question to make that clear.

Comment: @alexis But it would be possible to sort the filenames by same length. Given the definition above, that sequences have to be of same length (09, 10 is a valid sequence; 9, 10 is not). If filenames had different lengths they wouldn't be part of the same sequence. Then one could run the algorithm on all different filename lengths. But I honestly don't know what you mean by same-length buckets.

Comment: What I mean is exactly what you described. It's important because the comparison is only quadratic _within each length bucket._ If you have a thousand files, full pairwise checks mean 500,000 comparisons (one half of 1k*1k). If they come in 10 different lengths (say, 100 files for each length), you only need 50,000 comparisons (10 times 1/2*100*100).

Comment: You can speed up pairwise comparison by other means, but cutting down on the number of comparisons is always the biggest opportunity for large datasets.

Comment: @alexis Thanks for the input. That "bucket" explanation helped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first step could be this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
import re

names=[
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_xyz_05.png",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc09_xyz_05.png",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc10_xyz_05.JPG",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc15_xyz_05.JPG",
"fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc16_xyz_05.png",
"fde305be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png",
"fde309be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png",
"fde310be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png"
]

pat = re.compile(r'\d\d+')
seqs = defaultdict(list)
for name in names:
    k1 = pat.sub("#", name)
    k2 = tuple(m.span() for m in pat.finditer(name))
    seqs[(k1,k2)].append(name)

pprint(seqs)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {('fde#be-4d3e-xxxx_abc#_abc_#.png', ((3, 6), (22, 24), (29, 31))): ['fde305be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png',
                                                                                 'fde309be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png',
                                                                                 'fde310be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png'],
             ('fde#be-4d3e-xxxx_abc#_xyz_#.JPG', ((3, 6), (22, 24), (29, 31))): ['fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc10_xyz_05.JPG',
                                                                                 'fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc15_xyz_05.JPG'],
             ('fde#be-4d3e-xxxx_abc#_xyz_#.png', ((3, 6), (22, 24), (29, 31))): ['fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_xyz_05.png',
                                                                                 'fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc09_xyz_05.png',
                                                                                 'fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc16_xyz_05.png']})
```

This gives a dictionary whose values are lists of filenames which only differ between them for numeric characters in the same positions.

At this point we still have to a) discard "sequences" of lenght 1 and b) find in which position the names actually differ.

Step a) is trivial. As for step b) suppose we have "aaa01bbb02.jpg", "aaa02bbb02.jpg", "aaa01bbb03.jpg", so first and second names make a sequence, but first and third make another (while second and third differ in two places and so do not make a sequence): how would you handle this?

**EDIT**

Ok, based on OP's last answer here is a possible solution for the missing part:

```
trueseqs=[]
for k,v in seqs.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        continue
    for start,stop in reversed(k[1]):
        #start, stop = span
        diff = False
        for vi in v[:-1]:
            for j,vj in enumerate(v[1:]):
                if vi[start:stop] == vj[start:stop]:
                    continue
                if vi[:start]+vi[stop:] == vj[:start]+vj[stop:]:
                    diff = (start,stop)
                    trueseqs.append([[vi],diff])
                    print(f'insert {vi} with span {diff}')
                    break
            if diff:
                break
        for vh in v[j+1:]:
            if vi[start:stop] != vh[start:stop] and vi[:start]+vi[stop:] == vh[:start]+vh[stop:]:
                trueseqs[-1][0].append(vh)
                print(f'add    {vh}')
        if diff:
            break
insert fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_xyz_05.png with span (22, 24)
add    fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc09_xyz_05.png
add    fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc16_xyz_05.png
insert fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc10_xyz_05.JPG with span (22, 24)
add    fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc15_xyz_05.JPG
insert fde305be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png with span (3, 6)
add    fde309be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png
add    fde310be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png

pprint(trueseqs)
[[['fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_xyz_05.png',
   'fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc09_xyz_05.png',
   'fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc16_xyz_05.png'],
  (22, 24)],
 [['fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc10_xyz_05.JPG',
   'fde302be-4d3e-xxxx_abc15_xyz_05.JPG'],
  (22, 24)],
 [['fde305be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png',
   'fde309be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png',
   'fde310be-4d3e-xxxx_abc08_abc_05.png'],
  (3, 6)]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Now I understand what Jean-François Fabre meant with the dictionary. I'm unfortunately not an experienced programmer. As for step b): You are right, I didn't mention that. Given the data I'm working with I would always assume, that the sequence is at the end in this case, which is good enough in my case. So in your example "aaa02bbb02.jpg" would not be part of any sequence. But I haven't had that yet in my data. Thanks for the answer. That helped me quite a bit.